# How to download a valid Youtube video HTML page using Python?

Tags: python, html, http, web-scraping, youtube

Using `requests.get(URL, allow_redirects=True)` for Youtube, Reddit or other modern webpages gives a bunch of unexecuted JavaScript, rather than actual HTML text content that I would see when I open the page with a browser.

I just need to get the title of the video. How can I do that in a light way, without starting something heavy like selenium or puppeteer and without using Youtube API?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I was able to find the video title among all the Javascript and HTML.

```py
>>> import re
>>> r = requests.get("https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=UjLnvXpkq68", allow_redirects=True)
>>> m = re.search(r'"title":"(.*?)"', r.text)
>>> m.group(1)
'DJ OKAWARI「Perfect Blue」'
```

Probably not the prettiest solution but using regex lets you avoid having to parse the entire document.

Comment: You answered the question stated. Thank you!

Comment: Yet I need more than title for my project and extracting data with regex feels really primitive. By chance, do you know any methods that would make it easier to scrape through data hardcoded in javascript without interpreting the javascript?

Comment: If text values like title are what you want, then regex can help you more than you think. Or maybe you could look into [scrapy](https://scrapy.org/). The javascript would still have to be parsed using something like selenium, but scrapy takes care of it all and makes asynchronous calls for better performance.